# How to help mobile browsers handle multiple HTML5 audio and video objects on a single page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have a control console on a single page. Each button (of many buttons) on the control console will activate a new information panel which slides in from the right and:

- initiates a typing sequence (each character appears on the screen accompanied by a very short beep - each one is a new `Audio` object);
- plays a new `Audio` object, after several seconds, over the top of the ongoing beeping
- plays a second new `Audio` object, immediately afterwards,  over the top of the beeping (shortly after this point is usually where the beeps conclude)
- starts playing a new `Video` object after the beeps have concluded or shortly before they conclude

With laptop browsers (Firefox 58 and Chrome 64) I can cycle through any number of slide-in panels and the audio-visuals keep coming.

**N.B.** *Each new panel sliding in pauses all the `Audio` and `Video` objects from the previous panel.*

With mobile browsers on my Android Phone (Firefox and Chrome) the sound effects will start lagging on panel 2 or 3 and usually if I open a 5th or a 6th panel, all the audio and video gives up.

At this point javascript will no longer create a new `Audio` object nor play the HTML5 `<video>` element. Refreshing the page in the browser won't give it a new lease of life either. In fact the only option is to close the mobile browser and then re-open it.

I cannot be certain, but I am guessing that perhaps the browser is overloaded with objects and is responding by refusing to allow any more objects?

To test this theory, instead of:

```
var beep = new Audio('/beep.mp3');
beep.play;
```

I tried:

```
// GLOBAL SCOPE

var beeps = [];

// FUNCTION SCOPE

beeps[beeps.length] = new Audio('/.assets/media/audio/fixournhs/beep.mp3');
beeps[(beeps.length - 1)].play();

setTimeout(function(){

    if (beeps.length > 1) {
        beeps[0] = undefined;
        beeps.shift();
    }
}, 600);
```

But the same lag and eventual semi-shutdown occurs.

What is happening here? It's definitely mobile specific, because the browsers on my laptop are coping fine with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out - with a bit of lateral thinking - there was an alternative approach to producing the audio-visual typing sequence which does not require creating one new `Audio` object per letter and, consequently, does not create a large number of objects which then lead to lagging audio and lagging visuals.

The key is to have a single 5 second sound effect (ie. longer than any individual typing sequence) which emits a long continuous series of repetitive beeps.

The script then:

- activates the 5 second sound file with `.play()` at the same time as the letters start appearing
- stops the 5 second sound file with `this.pause(); this.currentTime = 0;` after the last letter has appeared

Because the beeps repeat at exactly (or almost) the same interval as the letters are appearing on the screen, the user is given a compelling impression that the beeps are associated with the letters (as they *actually were* when the sound effect comprised of a whole series of 0.3 second Audio objects).

Whereas in fact, the 5 second sound file being played is independent from the script which is making each letter appear in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var beep = new Audio('/beep.mp3');
beep.play;
beep.onended = function(){
    beep.remove() //Remove when played.
  };
```

That might help the browser know to delete your Beep audio objects when they're done.

If that test fails, try actually putting the 'beep' into the dom, with `document.body.appendChild(audio);`

Comment: Thank you for this - and plus one for utilising the `ended` event listener. I have tried out your suggested solution (and assorted variations thereof) but the lag (leading to a partial crash) is very much still there.